# A jdbc resource does not appear at the JDBC Resources node after deployed

Tags: java, mysql, windows, netbeans, web-applications

I'm working on a web application on NetBeans that uses a connection to DB (mySQL).

I created a jdbc resource with jdbc connection pool  then when I deployed  jdbc
resource but the problem is connection the jbdc resources doesn't appear in the JDBC nodes.
I already added mysqlconnector in libraries .my database appeared in "Databases" nodes...I think everything's okay.
please help!

[image]

and this is my class Connection.java

[image]

Comment: Look [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

Comment: I already did this :( my database works so fine ... also the deployment of the project ...

Comment: If you are showing your code please insert it directly into the question instead of uploading screen shots of your IDE / text editor. This makes it searchable for users who are having similar issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer it's pretty late but I hope this helps someone else, you can manually add the resource in glassfish admin console (usually localhost:4848).

Go to Resources -> Add Resources -> load the xml generated by netbeans

Doing this the connection pool and jdbc resource are created by glassfish.

[Here's an image of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBE5.png)