# new data source and connection pool are not displayed in the JDBC resources and Connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, glassfish, asadmin

I'm creating a system using netbeans IDE at some point I had to set up the data source and connection pool. I did that well but when I deploy the project the new data source and connection pool are not displayed on the JDBC resources and connection pool. I have figured I should add the reources by using the as admin command.

asadmin> add-resources c:\tmp\resource.xml

Command : JDBC resource jdbc1 created successfully.

Command : JDBC connection pool poolA created successfully.

Command add-resources executed successfully.

But I don't know where exactly do I write this code. Please will someone tell me where do I write the given glassfish asadmin command so that  I can add the resources.

Answer (score 0):

just add the resource on glassfish admin console.. Possible duplicate of  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029558/11451151)